# Connect CloudRun to CloudSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a web application running on Google's Cloud Run and I want to generate content from CloudSQL.

I have been looking at Google's documentation (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run)

It seems that Cloud Run can only connect to CloudSQL via sockets. When running the following block of code, I get "Connection refused":

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused


$dbName = 'databasename';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = 'password1';
$dbSocket = '/cloudsql/project:region:dbinstance';
$sqli = new mysqli(null, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, null, $dbSocket);
if ($sqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $sqli->connect_error);
}
```

All required Google APIs are enabled. Google supply an example for Python, Java, Node.js and Ruby in their documentation.

Comment: I tried to connect with your code and it worked just fine. As for the error you are receiving are you sure the Cloud Sql instance is not stopped? Usually this error indicates that server is not up or firewall is blocking or may be the service account doesn't have enough permissions.

Comment: Connection Refused typically means that the TCP/UDP port number that you are connecting to is not open (nobody listening). Double check 1) The connection string for correct project, region and instance name 2) What Cloud Run command line options where used to set up Cloud SQL. 3) Correct IAM roles assigned to the service account. 4) You say all correct roles are assigned. What roles are assigned to the service account that Cloud Run is using? Edit your question with how you configured everything.